# Storybook + Ngx-File-Drop - TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined at registerNgModuleType

Tags: angular, node-modules, storybook, angular-storybook

I'm using Angular 9 in conjunction with Storybook and when I attempt to add the NgxFileDropModule to my moduleMetadata imports, I receive the following error:

[Storybook Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdyrU.png)

I've added the NgxFileDropModule to the app.module.ts file like so:

```
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NgxFileDropModule,
    HttpClientModule,
],
```

And within the Storybook Story as:

```
export default {
title: 'Upload',
component: UploadComponent,
args: {},
decorators: [
    moduleMetadata({
        declarations: [UploadComponent, ButtonComponent, IconComponent],
        imports: [NgxFileDropModule],
    }),
],} as Meta;
```

I created a test project without Storybook and the error did not occur.

Answer (score 1):

For those who run into this problem in the future.

I ended up getting it working by reverting to ngx-file-drop v9.0.1, as anything above v10 caused this issue.

[Link to github issue](https://github.com/georgipeltekov/ngx-file-drop/issues/216)